# How to import super-csv-joda to use DateTime processor

Tags: supercsv

I'm currently using super-csv to read/write csv file from Java application.
Now, I need to deal with Joda DateTime object.
I see that there is a super-csv-joda module, but I can't found information about how to use it.
I tried to download it from Maven using super-csv-joda but that does not works.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Farid

Comment: I've just released Super CSV 2.3.0, so the Joda module should now be available :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you do great job! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joda extension is planned for the next release (`2.3.0`) - I'll try and get it organised for this week. If you're desperate, you can simply copy the required classes to your project for now.